Curved infinite scroll or marquee with custom logic
I have been struggling to build this(mention in picture). I want to make a curved marquee or infinite scroll carousel where each item, in this case flag will move from left to right. When a flag enter center of the viewport, in this case enter into window area - window background will be changed. How can I build this? For any kind of query please let me know.
note: any third party library like gsap can be used, I have no issue.


Do you have some code to start from?

Is this a good direction? https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/JjQmZYb

What does the background color of the window will change mean? A different color depending on the flag that’s entered it?

@AHaworth yes, depending on the flag that's entered.

@AntonijaŠimić yeh, you are on the right track obviously. And I have the marquee code but written for Next.js application, that's why I'm not included these here.

So does it go that color as soon as the flag starts to enter it and then go back to white as soon as the last bit of the flag has left it?

@AHaworth As soon as the flag enter the window, background color will change and remain until new flag is entered.

OK, thanks. That's the slightly more difficult bit, the rotation marquee is simply implemented with rotated divs with a flag at the top of each.

How many flags are you thinking of (I'm thinking of the overhead if there are many and we don't leverage eg a gpu).

There will be around 15-20 flags atmost.

Are you having an issue implementing the marquee/flag positioning logic or the background color changing or both? It's not quite clear in the question.

Here's a basic idea.
Each flag is 'on the end' of a div as background-image.
Each of those divs is placed centrally with width as you decide and placed apart from the next flag a distance around the arc of a circle that you define.
The height of the divs is then calculated to make this distance happen as they are placed rotated from a central point.
The whole is then rotated infinitely.
The changing color to a top rectangle is done separately, but with the same animation duration.
The keyframes for this set a CSS variable, --bg, to the background color that is relevant for the first, second etc flags.
This set up is only in CSS as a demo. In real life I would implement some JS to make the setting up less tedious and so the number of flags can be picked up from the DOM and the keyframes set accordingly.
I was worried about cpu usage, but it appears to be only a few % even on a simple laptop with no fancy gpu.


body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flags-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 25%, 0 25%);
  position: relative;
  --num: 20;
  /* number of flags */
  --a: 10vmin;
  /* set this to the distance along the arc between two flags that you want */
  --r: calc(2 * var(--a) * var(--num) / pi);
  --w: calc(2 * var(--r));
  width: var(--w);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: 15vmin;
  display: block;
}

.flags-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10%;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  animation: color 60s infinite linear;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    --bg: red;
  }
  5% {
    --bg: green;
  }
  10% {
    --bg: blue;
  }
  15% {
    --bg: black;
  }
  20% {
    --bg: cyan;
  }
  25% {
    --bg: magenta;
  }
  30% {
    --bg: yellow;
  }
  35% {
    --bg: red;
  }
  40% {
    --bg: green;
  }
  45% {
    --bg: blue;
  }
  50% {
    --bg: black;
  }
  55% {
    --bg: cyan;
  }
  60% {
    --bg: magenta;
  }
  65% {
    --bg: yellow;
  }
  70% {
    --bg: red;
  }
  75% {
    --bg: green;
  }
  80% {
    --bg: blue;
  }
  85% {
    --bg: black;
  }
  90% {
    --bg: cyan;
  }
  95% {
    --bg: magenta;
  }
  100% {
    --bg: red;
  }
}

.flags {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: rotate 60s infinite linear;
  top: 1vmin;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.flags>* {
  width: 5%;
  height: var(--r);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc((var(--n) - 1) * 360deg / var(--num)));
  --bgi: url(https://i.sstatic.net/Yjh0wFnx.webp);
  background-image: var(--bgi);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
  --bgi: url(https://i.sstatic.net/Yjh0wFnx.webp);
  /* REMEMBER to set --bgi for each flag */
}

.flags>*:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(6) {
  --n: 6;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(7) {
  --n: 7;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(8) {
  --n: 8;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(9) {
  --n: 9;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(10) {
  --n: 10;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(11) {
  --n: 11;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(12) {
  --n: 12;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(13) {
  --n: 13;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(14) {
  --n: 14;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(15) {
  --n: 15;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(16) {
  --n: 16;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(17) {
  --n: 17;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(18) {
  --n: 18;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(19) {
  --n: 19;
}

.flags>*:nth-child(20) {
  --n: 20;
}
<div class="flags-container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="flags">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .mask1 {
    mask-image: linear-gradient(black 0 100px, transparent 100px 100%);
    mask-size: 100px 100px;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: 50% 10%;
    background-image: conic-gradient(red, yellow, blue, green);
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
  }



